# starting exe with two param with powershell

Tags: powershell

I need to create a powershell script that launch  an exe file which also has two parameters, I want to put it in a group policy, so that it starts at the power on of each computer.
I tried this command:

```
$Username = 'user'
$Password = 'pass'
$pass = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $Password -Force
$Cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $Username, $pass
invoke-command -Credential $Cred -ScriptBlock {& 'C:\myfile.exe' --param1 value --param2}
```

It tells me

```
Invoke-Command : Impossibile risolvere il set di parametri utilizzando i parametri denominati specificati.
In riga:1 car:1
+ invoke-command  -Credential $Cred -ScriptBlock { & 'C:\Program Files  ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-Command], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameterSet,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeCommandCommand
```

I also tried this:

```
invoke-command -Credential $Cred -ScriptBlock {Start-Process -FilePath 'C:\myfile.exe' -ArgumentList "--param1 value", "-psb4"}
```

but the error that appears is the same.

Comment: This `-Credential $ Cred` should be this `-Credential $Cred`. This is true of your script block above also, you can't have a space between the $ and variable name.

Comment: Also extra spaces in `-FilePath 'C: \ myfile.exe'`...

Comment: sorry for the spaces, it was only a paste issue. Now I remove the spaces in the post

Comment: @JohnDoe Please post the error message in its entirety

Comment: The use of `-Credential` parameter also requires `-ComputerName`